# EF Core and Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have managed to implement EntityFramework Core service to work with SqlServer, how about the Azure?

Here is my code: 
project.json dependency:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0"
```

And my Setup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<WorldContext>();
    }
```

Is there a provider to work against cloud Azure database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the connection string of your Azure database. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` works for both regular SQL Server as SQL Azure.

> This database provider allows Entity Framework Core to be used with
>   Microsoft SQL Server (including SQL Azure).

Source: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/sql-server/index.html

Comment: Make sure the timeout value is high enough in the connection string. When you copy the default string from Azure, the timeout is 30 seconds.